# Is it possible to send a gift anonymously or at least without them knowing beforehand?

Tags: steam

I want to send someone a gift as I may or may not be involved in a secret santa on steam.

Ideally I don't want them to know I sent it at all (the secret part) but I guess steam will tell them who sent it. Failing that, I'd like them to not know it was me until the gift notification turns up in steam. I'll send a custom message so they know it's part of the secret santa.

I'm guessing people aren't going to want to post email addresses around, so **is it possible to send a gift via steam without their email address and not adding them as a friend?**

I have a link to their profile.

Comment: You could try making a new steam account and adding them from there.

Comment: @victoriah that usually doesn't work since new steam accounts dont' have any privileges unless it owns one(paid) game

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried sending myself a gift just now - the email contains the sender's email address, indeed. What you can do is send a gift to your own secondary email address, and send them the URL for redeeming the gift (the URL you receive by emailing the gift to yourself) . Hopefully you have some way of contacting them other than their steam profile; for example, give them the url written on a slip of paper.

Caution: The URL contains the email you sent the gift to. If you don't want the receiver to be able to guess who you are, and the secondary email you're sending to is obviously related to you, create a new email account to send to. Example URL, email highlighted:

> https://store.steampowered.com/account/ackgift/1F631467BB7E?redeemer=**Fadeway%40yahoo.com**

With this method, the first time they learn the sender's name will be when they enter the URL into a browser:

[image]

If there's no way to transmit the URL to them without posting on their steam profile, that's a lost cause, unless you get a third person to act as an arbiter/organizer who friends everybody and distributes the links while keeping it a secret who sent which one.

Comment: Probably too late for the person asking the question, but the third-party organizer is a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the article about gifting: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6262-QXCN-0755

Unfortunately, you can't send a gift anonymously.

No matter how you send it from your account, your recipient will see your Steam profile name and/or the e-mail address that your account was registered with. Even if your change your community profile name, they can look at the previous names you've used.

Comment: I get that I can't send it anonymously, but can I make it so the first they know about it is when it's received (not when the get a friend request)?

Answer (score 4):

The information below was correct at the time of writing, unfortunately it is no longer true. Gifts purchased now can no longer be stored in inventory or re-gifted onwards.

---

If this is part of a secret santa then presumablly there is some kind of organiser who knows the pairings.

If the orgnaiser has a steam account then as far as I can tell you should be able to gift the game to them and they should be able to receive it into their inventory (NOT their library) and gift it onwards to the final receipiant.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible for games, however it is possible to gift someone Steam Wallet credit using Steam Gift Cards or Wallet Codes.

See: https://store.steampowered.com/account/redeemwalletcode

Answer (score 1):

You can use [usendme.net](http://usendme.net)  You don't have to know all the details about the person but you do have to be able to tell them you have sent a gift.  Otherwise you don't need to know anything about them - not even their name.